# Adding documents to firestore using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a function to add documents to firestore. At the moment this function could be called two different ways. 1) Adding a user to a collection called 'Users'. 2) adding a site to a collection called 'Sites'.

This function should take the following parameters:

1. The name of the collection (required)
2. The users uid (make this optional)
3. An object with the data for a site (make this optional)

I'm also trying to utilize JS modules to keep my code better organised. At the moment my folder looks something like this:

```
myApp
  assets
    img
  dist
    index.html
    index.js
  modules
    auth.js
    firestore.js
```

Inside auth.js I have a signUp() inside witch I want to call a function called addToFirestore() **(this comes from firestore.js)**. My code looks something like this:

**firestore.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase- 
app.js';

import { getFirestore, setDoc, doc } from 
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase-firestore.js';

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore;

function addToFirestore(collName, user = 0, data = 0) {
  // check if adding user
  if (user != 0 && data == 0){
    //adding user to firestore
    try {
      setDoc(doc(db, collName, user.uid), {
        email: user.email,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error adding document: ', e);
    }
  // check if adding site
} else if (data != 0 && user == 0) {
  setDoc(doc(db, collName), data);
}

export { addToFirestore};
```

Inside **auth.js** calling function like this:

```
// * Auth
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase-auth.js';

import {addToFirestore} from '/modules/firestore.js';

function signUp(email, password) {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      addToFirestore('Users', user);
    })
    .then(() => {
      openApp();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      alertAuth.classList.remove('d-none');
      alertAuth.classList.add('show');
      alertAuth.innerHTML = `<strong>Error: </strong> ${errorCode}`;
    });
}
```

And inside **index.js** calling signUp():

```
btnAuthSignUp.addEventListener('click', function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  let email = inpAuthEmail.value;
  let password = inpAuthPassword.value;

  signUp(email, password);
});
```

And it is giving me an error like this:

> firestore.js:31 Error adding document:  FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

I tried doing everything in one file and still got the same problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make it clear in your question which line of code is causing the error.  Your code should also strive to show the actual values of any variables so we can easily reproduce the issue on our own.

Comment: Hi @Kevin Vaha, have you tried my posted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on the error you encountered:

> Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore.

Firestore expects a collection reference to pass the data to. You didn't specify your collection reference. You should put a collection reference by using given code below:

```
const collectionRef = doc(db, 'collection_name', user.uid);
```

`db` here is not a collection reference. Its just an instance of Firestore:

```
const db = getFirestore;
```

Then use it as code below:

```
setDoc(collectionRef, {
        email: user.email,
      });
```

You could also check [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) for more information.